# OneStepCheckout shipping method problem

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

In my e-commerce when I try to estimate shipping in checkout page and then I click the button "proceed checkout" I get a white page in /checkout/onepage/, both if I estimate only and if I estimate and then select "free shipping" radio button. The white page is without Apache errors and without javascript console errors; there are no errors in var/log/system.log and there is no exception.log file in the same directory.
Instead, if I don't get estimation and proceed directly to the checkout, in /checkout/onepage/ I have no shipping method enabled so I can't proceed to checkout. On what it could depend on?

**Configuration**:

- Magento CE 1.9.3.2 with SUPEE-9767
- Onestepcheckout from Em Magento Everything theme; if I disable it and set default Magento Onestepcheckout, I don't get white page but I can't proceed to the next step because it shows the message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."
- The only shipping method enabled is "Free shipping" with minimum order zero for all permitted country, that actually is Italy

Comment: Hi bquindo, welcome to Magento Stack Exchange site. The info that you have provided is not enough to help you out. In order to get more details of what exactly goes wrong with your custom theme, you need to look into your browser console, while you checkout. If you can find some errors in the ajax request for the shipment request, then update that error with this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the issue in:

```
 /app/design/frontend/em0131/em0131_garden/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

I've got

```
var_dump($_shippingRateGroups);
```

that **returned blank page without any type of error**. I removed it and the checkout works now.

Comment: If you look into the error log of your webserver, you will see that it's an error because your memory-limit is too low. You can't `var_dump` most of the objects in Magento. Some classes have a `debug()` method that returns a reduced instance that can be dumped.

Comment: As I said there wasn't any error in CPanel error_log, that is weird. 
Thank you very much for the hint about var_dump and debug()!